# Diabetic vs non-diabetic dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for information for a research. I need some data on a group of diabetic people and a group of non-diabetic people.

This is some of the information I need:

- Age
- Body mass index
- [Fasting blood sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose_test)

Any ideas where I can find these data?

I prefer data from Brazil, but if you have this data from other countries I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You need to contact the Government of Brazil to see if they have the data.

Comment: You might want to try this Health group and someone might answer to your post  http://health.stackexchange.com/